# <table> con un <tr> de un solo <td>

Tags: c#, html5, asp.net

Buenas, quiero que mi tabla en html quede con una sola columna en una fila, algo asi como un titulo, parecido a esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Me refiero a la celda que dice Sign Up, el codigo en ella es el siguiente:

```
<-tr>
    <-td align="center" colspan="2">Sign Up</td>  
    <-asp:Label runat="server" Text="Sign Up"></asp:Label>  
<-/tr>
```

Agregue los guiones antes del comienzo de la etiqueta para que no las interprete el cuadro de texto.

¿Por que agregue el asp:Label?
Porque ocurre esto si lo quito:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Codigo completo:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="SignUp.aspx.cs" Inherits="SignUpn" %>

<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="SignUp.aspx.cs" Inherits="SignUpn" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
<title></title>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function alerta(numero) {
        alert("Hay un campo vacío.");
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
    <table bgcolor="#1abc9c" border="1">

        <tr>
            <td align="center" colspan="2">Sign Up</td>
            <asp:Label runat="server" Text="Sign Up"></asp:Label>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td align="left">
                <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="Name"></asp:Label>
            </td>
            <td align="center">
                <asp:TextBox ID="textBoxName" MaxLength="16" runat="server" Width="100%"></asp:TextBox>
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td align="left">
                <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text="Last name"></asp:Label>
            </td>

            <td align="center">
                <asp:TextBox ID="textBoxLastName" MaxLength="16" runat="server" Width="100%"></asp:TextBox>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="left">
                <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Password"></asp:Label>
            </td>

            <td align="center">
                <asp:TextBox ID="textBoxPassword" TextMode="Password" MaxLength="16" runat="server" Width="100%" ></asp:TextBox>
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td align="left">
                <asp:Label ID="Label5" runat="server" Text="Re-password"></asp:Label>
            </td>

            <td align="center">
                <asp:TextBox ID="textBoxRePassword" TextMode="Password" runat="server" Width="100%"></asp:TextBox>
            </td>
        </tr>

         <tr>
            <td align="left">
                <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text="E-mail"></asp:Label>
            </td>

            <td align="center">
                <asp:TextBox ID="textBoxEmail" TextMode="Email" MaxLength="32" runat="server" Width="100%"></asp:TextBox>
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td align="center">
                <asp:Label runat="server" Text="Type of account"></asp:Label>
            </td>

            <td>
                <asp:RadioButtonList runat="server" ID="radioListTypes" >
                    <asp:ListItem Selected="True">Commercial</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>Personal</asp:ListItem>
                </asp:RadioButtonList>

            </td>
        </tr>




        <tr>
            <td>
                <asp:Button ID="buttonCancel" runat="server" Text="Cancel" Width="100%"/>
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:Button ID="buttonSignUp" runat="server" Text="OK" Width="100%" OnClick="buttonSignUp_Click"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>

</form>

</body>
```

Les agradeceria la aclaración.

Comment: podrias mostrar tu html entero? aca c# y asp.net no tienen nada que ver por mas que estes trabajando con eso.. el problema es puramente el html..

Comment: He agregado el código completo.

Comment: borre todo el asp, lo puse como texto y la tabla se ve bien, como el ejemplo de arriba.. debes tener un tag mal.. probaste ir agregando de a uno?

Comment: Al igual que @gbianchi, la tabla se me ve perfecto. Sera que probablemente tengas una etiqueta mal formada?

Comment: Parece que en el penúltimo <tr>... tienes mal los <td>, se ve como si fueran tres.

Answer (score 1):

Intenta ponerlo de la siguiente manera:

```
<-tr>
    <-td align="center" colspan="2">
        <-asp:Label runat="server" Text="Sign Up"></asp:Label>
    </td>
<-/tr>
```

Comment: Al parecer tienes el texto de 'Sign Up' dos veces, incluso el asp:Label lo tienes fuera de tu 'td'. Como lo dice Alfredo, con que pongas solo uno y dentro de tu 'td' se debería de corregir tu formato.